@EntityScan and multiple EntityManagerFactories/Datasource: filter out packages
I have a spring boot application with two LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean which connect to two different databases. I have created different @Entity and configured the @EntityScan. Both databases have the tables already created at the time spring starts to validate the schema.
The problem is that at start up the app fails to create the first LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean because, during schema validation, it doesn't find the table in the database 1, but that's fine since the table is in database 2 and should be validated by LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 2. Is there a way to filter out the validation of entities under a certain package?
Since I have more packages, with entities that should be managed by the first LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean I would prefer an exclude mechanism instead of a include mechanism.

Don't use @EntityScan specify the packages to scan through the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean instead. @EntityScan is only useful when using a single LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and you have multiple jars/packages that contain entities.
